# YouTube API : Error 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have a page on my localhost from where users can upload videos. Now I'd like to implement the function, where admins can make those videos public (users must upload them as private videos).
Now for that, first of all I need to get a list of all videos on channel (including the private ones). I tried this code:

```
    $data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
                <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
                  xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
                </entry>';
    $headers = array( "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$authvalue,
                 "GData-Version: 2",
                 "X-GData-Key: key=".$youtube_key,
                 "Content-length: ".strlen( $data ),
                 "Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");
    $curl = curl_init( "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads");
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
```

which returns with this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:....
```

I couldn't find the proper form of headers for requesting a list of user videos, so I used the one which I apply for uploading videos (and which works, so I am certain there is not a problem with user authentication).

If you could tell me what I am doing wrong or just point me to an example of working video listing, I'd be very grateful.

edit:
curl_error returns an empty string, curl_info returns this:

```
array (size=26)
  'url' => string 'https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/.../uploads' (length=80)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
  'http_code' => int 400
  'header_size' => int 597
  'request_size' => int 1747
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 20
  'redirect_count' => int 1
  'total_time' => float 0.639
  'namelookup_time' => float 0.047
  'connect_time' => float 0.078
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0.172
  'size_upload' => float 0
  'size_download' => float 925
  'speed_download' => float 1447
  'speed_upload' => float 0
  'download_content_length' => float 925
  'upload_content_length' => float 0
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.203
  'redirect_time' => float 0.436
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_ip' => string '173.194.70.117' (length=14)
  'primary_port' => int 443
  'local_ip' => string '10.0.0.33' (length=9)
  'local_port' => int 53639
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: get the detailed error message via `curl_error` and detailed response from `curl_info`. Everything starts with debug. End your curl with `curl_close()` too.

Comment: Sorry, I only forgot to copy the curl_close :)
The curl_close() returns an empty string.
curl_getinfo() returns an array about the 400 page I got (filesize, download speed, loading time..) and some information about IPs and ports used.

Comment: can you double confirm the HTTP status code in `curl_info()` is 400 ?

Comment: Yes, it is 400. I've added the complete content of curl_info in the post.

Comment: Actually, did you follow the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Authentication ? It looks quite different from your code.

Comment: Well I tried to derive the code from this example of youtube uploader: http://www.rd2inc.com/blog/2012/08/youtube-browser-based-uploader-with-php/ ... which works perfectly for me. I think the error here could be in wrong headers / curl options. I didn't know about the Zend library though. Will try and look into that a bit. Thank you.

Comment: for Zend Library , you can use `phpinfo()` to check whether you installed it.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I've managed to get the video listing working using the Zend library. Thank you so much!

Comment: I noticed that you have 2 `curl_init()`. It's abnormal. Do you intend to do so ?

Comment: Oops, sorry. That ClientLogin curl_init is from a different part of the script, I must've mixed it in somehow when I was adding the code snippet.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to add `[SOLVED]`; that's not how StackOverflow works. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101 and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the comments above, installing Zend library with [Zend_Gdata](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.html) ( version >= 1.7.7 ) extension solved the problem. Also noted that PHP version must be >= 5.1.4 .

Reference: [Google YouTube API - PHP](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must try php trim function on each of the params you are sending in this cURL call.
Like

```
"Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".trim($authvalue),
                 "GData-Version: 2",
                 "X-GData-Key: key=".trim($youtube_key),
                 "Content-length: ".trim(strlen($data)),
```

And it should work.

Comment: The keys are already trimmed before (see http://www.rd2inc.com/blog/2012/08/youtube-browser-based-uploader-with-php/ ). And trimming them once again had no effect. I already solved this issue using the Zend Gdata library which is much much easier to work with. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: That is where you got this script from?

Comment: Yup, I tried to edit it / find a working example of video feed using curl, but I wasn't successful. But it doesn't matter now as it is solved. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Its a stolen one.I had written this script actually.And I am amazed that some one took it from me and posted it on his blog.

Comment: And your this error may be due to some bad header you are sending to google.